# Как хранить плотную матрицы с целью параллельного умножения?

Tags: c++, матрицы

Какой наилучший способ для хранения плотной матрицы с целью параллельного умножения матрицы на матрицу?

```
1) std::vector<std::vector<double>>

2) std::valarray<std::valarray<double>>

3) std::vector<double> // последовательно

4) std::valarray<double> // последовательно

5) ... ?
```

Comment: Дерево. Найдите быстрый алгоритм умножения, где матрицы делят пополам. Умножают отдельно, потом складывают. Сначала ищем алгоритм, потом реализация скажет как хранить.

Comment: https://e-maxx.ru/algo/segment_tree это с небольшими модификациями должно помочь